# C++ read text line-by-line, speed/efficiency savings needed

Tags: c++

I have a series of large text files (10s - 100s of thousands of lines) that I want to parse line-by-line. The idea is to check if the line has a specific word/character/phrase and to, for now, record to a secondary file if it does.

The code I've used so far is:

```
ifstream infile1("c:/test/test.txt");
while (getline(infile1, line)) {
    if (line.empty()) continue;
    if (line.find("mystring") != std::string::npos) {
        outfile1 << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

The end goal is to be writing those lines to a database. My thinking was to write them to the file first and then to import the file.

The problem I'm facing is the time taken to complete the task. I'm looking to minimize the time as far as possible, so any suggestions as to time savings on the read/write scenario above would be most welcome. Apologies if anything is obvious, I've only just started moving into C++.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I should say that I'm using VS2015

**EDIT 2**

So this was my own dumb fault, when switching to Release and changing the architecture type I had noticeable speed increases. Thanks to everyone for pointing me in that direction. I'm also looking at the mmap stuff and that's proving useful too. Thanks guys!

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations?

Comment: my 2 cents...Reading each line from a file will reduce the speed. Try to use system calls (hope you are using linux).1.use mmap  (or) 2. use fstat or stat to know the file size.dynamically allocate the memory for that size.read the whole file in one shot,then do the process.

Comment: How about storing matching lines (vector, perhaps) and writing to the database when the vector gets to a certain size (and when you get to the end of the input data)?

Comment: @KerrekSB only defaults, default is for speed?

Comment: The most expensive thing in that loop is the find operation, which I presume is a linear search of line for "mystring".  Finding a better way to determine you have a match will save significant time.  IO ( reading the data, writing to your second file) is your next big cost in time, minimizing the number of read/write system calls issued will reduce the amount of time spent in the loop.  Read up on ifstream buffering to convince yourself that it's working the way you think it does.

Comment: @NaveenKumar I'm in Windows using VS2015, I should have stated, sorry.

Comment: @dailygrind Did you compile in debug or release mode?

Comment: If you are working on Linux, try using a nawk script. I have used it with files containing millions of records and found it to be very efficient.

Comment: @dailygrind the default config in VS is debug... switch it to release and profile again

Comment: You could read the file in large chunks (e.g. 4kB), then search for the needle, and *then* search for the surrounding line endings. That's what `grep` does, too.

Comment: The `line.empty()` check seems redundant; `find` should return immediately in that case.

Comment: @NaveenKumar Your recommendations are exactly the reverse of what is required. He should *minimize* system calls by using large buffers, and there is exactly zero advantage to reading the entie file into memory before processing any of it: more probably, a pronounced disadvantage, by adding latency, wasting memory, and increased swapping.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ifstream` to read and process to/from really big files, you have to increase the default buffer size that is used (normally 512 bytes).

The best buffer size depends on your needs, but as a hint you can use the partition block size of the file(s) your reading/writing. To know that information you can use a lot of tools or even code.

Example in Windows:

```
fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c:
```

Now, you have to create a new buffer to `ifstream` like this:

```
size_t newBufferSize = 4 * 1024; // 4K
char * newBuffer = new char[newBufferSize];
ifstream infile1;
infile1.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(newBuffer, newBufferSize);
infile1.open("c:/test/test.txt");
while (getline(infile1, line)) {
    /* ... */
}
delete newBuffer;
```

Do the same with the output stream and don't forget set new buffer before open file or it may not work.

You can play with values to find the very best size for you.

You'll note the difference.

Answer (score 0):

C-style I/O functions are much faster than fstream.
You may use fgets/fputs to read/write each text line.